# Get matrix $A^{n}$ problem with eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

i have problem with some matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
         2    & \frac{1}{2}
  \end{bmatrix}$

To get $A^{n} = P J^{n} P^{-1}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{2} - \lambda & 0 \\
         2    & \frac{1}{2} - \lambda
  \end{bmatrix}$

$J^{n} =\begin{bmatrix}
  (\frac{1}{2})^{n} & n(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1} \\
         0    & (\frac{1}{2})^{n}
  \end{bmatrix}$
i'm not sure how to create this matrix

So the eigenvaues are $\lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2} = \frac{1}{2}$
then 
$\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
   2    & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  \end{bmatrix}$ =
$\begin{bmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
  \end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvector are : $\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
  0\\
  \end{bmatrix}$

The question is: How look like $P$ matrix?

edit: So the answer will be:
$A^{n} =\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
  1 & 1\\
  \end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
  (\frac{1}{2})^{n} & n(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1} \\
         0    & (\frac{1}{2})^{n}
  \end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
  -2 & 1\\
  2 & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}$

Is that right?

Comment: What is $J$ here?

Comment: @Bernard I guess it's the Jordan normal form  of $A$.

Comment: @JohneQue Yes, that's true! P.S. In order to fix the size of the parentheses when fractions are involved, you can use something like: `$\left(\frac 12\right)^n$`

Comment: Okeyyy :D thank you very much :D you saved me like 10houres to solve it on my own :D. One more if you have one minutes :D i get this from internet but i'm not sure why is that how matrix $J =\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
         0    & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}$ was change to matrix $J^{n}$ ?? How matrix are increased to unknown power?

Comment: @JohneQue It is true that  $A = P \cdot J \cdot P^{-1} \implies A^n = P\cdot J^n \cdot P^{-1}$. This implication is true due to the way matrix $P$ is defined (its columns contain the right hand eigenvectors) and $J$ is the normal Jordan form. Now, if you have any question about how $J^n$ can be calculated, evaluate $J^2, J^3,\ldots$ and check if you can see any pattern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues are indeed $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda =\frac 12$. The matrix $P$ contains as its columns the right hand (generalized) eigenvectors of $A$, which are linearly independent. Solving the system $$(A- \lambda I) \mathbf{v} =\mathbf 0\iff \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$ yields that $x = 0$ and $y \in \mathbb R^*$ (since the zero vector cannot be an eigenvector).Thus, we can consider the eigenvector $\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$

Due to $\dim V_{\lambda} = 1,$ in order to define matrix $P$ we need to find a [generalized eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Overview_and_definition)  $\mathbf w$ of rank $2$, such that $$\left(A-\frac 12 I\right)^2\mathbf w = \mathbf 0\\[2ex]
\text {and} \\[2ex]
\left(A- \frac 12 I\right)\mathbf w \neq \mathbf 0.$$ For that reason we define the vector $\mathbf w $ as the solution of the system $$\left(A- \frac 12 I\right) \mathbf w = \mathbf v.$$

That means we have to solve the linear system $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\2 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot\begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

The matrix $P$ is equal to $P  = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & w_1 \\ 1 & w_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Can you fill in the details?

Comment: Yee i got something like this : 
$w_{1}  = \frac{1}{2}$ 
$ 0 = 0$
In this case P looks like this $P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\  1 & w_{2} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: But from where can i get $w_{2}$ ?? It could be random number ? like 1?

Comment: I edited could you check if it should be like this?

Comment: @thanasissdr This link you provided is very useful. What I don't  understand is that in example 1 it says that the matrix is not diagonalizable. But that matrix is essentially the same as the matrix in this post, yet the OP put a diagonalizable form of it. I don't understand this.

Comment: @imranfat Yes, you are right about the non - diagonalizable matrix $A$. If matrix $A$ was diagonalizable, then its Jordan normal form would be a diagonal matrix. But here, that's not the case. Indeed, $J = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$ is not a diagonal matrix.